# How to show images in the folder that have a same name with php?

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to display images that have a same first name in a folder. For example IMG1-car.jpg, IMG1-truck.jpg and IMG1-bus.jpg. IN the example, I want to display the image that has a same name, IMG1.

Here's my code, but it displays all of images in a folder.

```
$curdir = $section_id."/";
$images = getImages($basedir,$curdir); 
if($images) {
    foreach($images as $img) { 
        $imglist .= '<img style="margin:03px;" src="'.$baseurl.$curdir.'thumbs/'.basename($img['file']).'" alt="'.$baseurl.$curdir.basename($img['file']).'" title="'.$baseurl.$curdir.basename($img['file']).'">';
    } 
}
```

Here's my getImages code :

```
$basedir = WB_PATH.MEDIA_DIRECTORY.'/images/';
$baseurl = WB_URL.MEDIA_DIRECTORY.'/images/';


if (!function_exists('getImages')) {
    function getImages($basedir,$dir) {
        $retval = array();
        $imagetypes = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
        if(substr($dir, -1) != "/")  $dir .= "/";
        $fulldir = $basedir.''.$dir;
        $d = @dir($fulldir) or die("getImages: Failed opening directory $fulldir for reading");
        while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
          if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
          if(in_array(mime_content_type($fulldir.$entry), $imagetypes)) {
            $retval[] = array( "file" => ''.$dir.$entry );
          }
        }
        $d->close();
        asort($retval);
        return $retval;
    }
}
```

I don't use database to store the name of file, so I'm still confused how to display image that has a same value in a folder. Anybody Help me...

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be related with question at all. And you haven't posted the function getImages.

Comment: @ShamalSandeep The code is very much related to the question! You may want to use `substr()`. How are you identifying the `IMG1-` bit though - do you know the images all start with that or are you expecting PHP to be able to work it out?

Comment: Sorry, I will post the getImages code

Comment: `glob('/path/to/dir/IMG01*.jpg')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
$curdir = $section_id."/";
$images = getImages($basedir,$curdir); 
if($images) {
    foreach($images as $img) { 
        if(strpos($baseurl.$curdir.'thumbs/'.basename($img['file']) , $baseurl.$curdir.'thumbs/IMG1' )!==false){
            $imglist .= '<img style="margin:03px;" src="'.$baseurl.$curdir.'thumbs/'.basename($img['file']).'" alt="'.$baseurl.$curdir.basename($img['file']).'" title="'.$baseurl.$curdir.basename($img['file']).'">';
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
$curdir = $section_id."/";
$images = getImages($basedir,$curdir); 
if($images) {
    foreach($images as $img) { 
        $startWith = 'IMG1';
        if(substr($img['file'], 0 , strlen($startWith)) == $startWith)
        {
            $imglist .= '<img style="margin:03px;" src="'.$baseurl.$curdir.'thumbs/'.basename($img['file']).'" alt="'.$baseurl.$curdir.basename($img['file']).'" title="'.$baseurl.$curdir.basename($img['file']).'">';
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the segments of your filename are always separated by the same character, like a dash in your example, you can explode on its name and only display it if the name fits the criteria.

(untested code, but you get the gist)

```
$curdir = $section_id."/";
$images = getImages($basedir,$curdir);
$name = 'IMG1'; 
if($images) {
    foreach($images as $img) { 
        $nameArray= explode('-',$img['file']);
        if (isset($nameArray[0] && $nameArray[0] == $name) {
            $imglist .= '<img style="margin:03px;" src="'.$baseurl.$curdir.'thumbs/'.basename($img['file']).'" alt="'.$baseurl.$curdir.basename($img['file']).'" title="'.$baseurl.$curdir.basename($img['file']).'">';
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, it´s pretty simple. First, I will declare a function to handle it more easily:

```
function startsWith($string, $start){ 
    return $start === "" || strpos($string, $start) === 0; 
}
```

And then, using your example:

```
$curdir = $section_id."/";
$images = getImages($basedir,$curdir); 
if($images) {
    foreach($images as $img) { 
        if ( !startsWith(basename($img['file'], "IMG1") ) continue;
        $imglist .= '<img style="margin:03px;" src="'.$baseurl.$curdir.'thumbs/'.basename($img['file']).'" alt="'.$baseurl.$curdir.basename($img['file']).'" title="'.$baseurl.$curdir.basename($img['file']).'">';
    } 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$handle = opendir(dirname(realpath(__FILE__)) . '/pictures/');
while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
         echo '<img style="margin:10px;" src="pictures/' . $file . '" border="0" />';      
    }
}
```